# Does a graph with seven vertices: one vertex of degree 1, one of degree 2, one of degree 3, ... exist?

Tags: graph-theory

> Give an example of a simple and undirected graph for each one of the specified
>   conditions, or reason why no such graph exists:
>   A graph with seven vertices: one vertex of degree 1, one of degree 2, one of
>   degree 3, two vertices of degree 4, one of degree 5, and one vertex of degree 6.

The sequence of the graph degree is : 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 25 degrees.

By using the Handshake theorem the total edges of the graph is : 
25 / 2 = 12.5 which is an odd number - which means, the graph dosen't exist.

Correct or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. The handshake Lemma is a necessary condition for a graph to exist. It isn't sufficient though. Havel and Hakimi gave a characterization of degree sequences that are graphic, as did Erdos and Gallai.